# Not detecting escape key C#

Tags: c#, keydown

First of all greetings to everybody, for this is my first post.

i'm new in C# so it may be that the solution is obvious.

I have a datagridview with names and dates data. When double click on a date column a datetimepicker is shown for date to be picked. If Escape is hit, datetimepicker is hidden and the old data takes effect.
When the code is run and if I double click on the date column in the last row, datetimepicker pops up, but escape in not being read.
If the same is done in some row before the last, esc is working fine.
If the same is done firstly in some other row and then in the last row, again the esc is working fine.
The only problem is when datetimepicker is activated firstly in the last row. Also stand for Enter key

Used for key reading and datetimepicker handling

```
private void dateTimePicker1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) { CellAddValue(1, dateTimePicker1.Value); }
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape) { CellAddValue(1, dateWhenSelDate); }
}

public void CellAddValue(int o, DateTime date)
{
    string dateString = date.ToString(dateFormat);
    if (DateTime.Compare(date, dateTimePicker1.MinDate) == 0) { dateString = ""; }
    dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRow].Cells[selectedColumn].Value = dateString;
    if (o == 1)
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Hide();
        dataGridView1.Focus();
    }
}
```

Is there some settings or options that i must set to be able to work?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Think this is a win-form application

Have a look at [Form.KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You need to set

```
From.KeyPreview = true;
```

Comment: Thank for the help.
It did not solve the problem.
I still don't know why is like that.
I manage to do it in other way.
Datagrid was parent for datetimepicker. By changing that and adjusting the position of picker, i have the same effect.

Comment: I found that I can't detect Escape (by whichever method) as long as Photoshop (CS2) is running..

Answer (score 0):

To get a detailed control over all key presses you can overwrite the ProcessCmdKey method of your form, that way you intercept ALL key events:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    string keyName = keyData.ToString(); // You might rather use the Keys. enum

    if ("Escape".Equals(keyName))
    {
        Action();
        return true; // If you return true the key event won't be treated any further
    }
    else // pass the key on to your forms, they will be treated as if this method wasn't here
    {
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

I usually use this with

```
formInstance.KeyPreview = true;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx